# C# Regex meet first match and take everything from start of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string input which looks like:

```
var price = "£1.33(including postage)";
```

I'd like to take out the first part of the string before ( so that the output of regex would look like this:

```
"£1.33"
```

I'm new with Regex so I'm not quite sure how to do this, can someone help me out?

P.S. I thought of doing a substring, but that wouldn't work since price can have more decimals, and can be a larger price, so this option definitely wouldn't work

Comment: `I'd like to take out the first part of the string before (` - in that case the new string would be `(including postage)` ?? To match that, you'd have to say _up until the first literal (_. If that's the same all the time, it's this `^[^(]+`

Comment: Forget about regex for a while, you need to define the problem first. What format can the input have? "$25-30", "approx. 15,4€", "have no idea"... What is the possible input?

Comment: Your question is too broad, see Antonin's comment. I also think the current problem can be solved by `Regex.Replace(s, @"\([^)]*\)", "")`, remove all `(...)` from the string.

Comment: Also why would a substring not work? You can do a string find on the character you know will be constant after the price decimal, say your "(", get the index and substring based on that for your string to convert.

Comment: You don't need Regex for this if you have the same basic format of the "price" just different values.  Try `var result = price.Substring(0, price.IndexOf("("));`.

Answer (score 1):

do you have to use regex?
much easier if you use split

```
string result = price.Split('(').First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regex for this if you have the same basic format of the "price" just different values.

```
var result = price.Substring(0, price.IndexOf("("));.
```